# First evaluation of $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2$ by Fourier series

Tags: mathematics, discoveries, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

There are many ways to evaluate $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2$ as $\pi^2/6$, including multiple solutions using Fourier series. A colleague asked me who was the *first* person to use Fourier series (or Fourier analysis) to make this computation. I don't know and was unable to figure this out. Any concrete evidence that a particular person was the first to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: It must have been before Kummer (1846).

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer, can you clarify why?  For example, did Kummer include such a solution in something he wrote in which it was clear the idea was not due to him?

Comment: If no one comes up with something better I will add details. Kummer discussed more complicated sums in connection with cubic Gauss sums and did not give references. He might have learned this from Dirichlet . . .

Answer (score 2):

Kummer's interest in this question is due to the problem of the location of cubic Gauss sums, analogous to Gauss's determination of the sign of quadratic Gauss sums. In *De residuis cubicis disquisitiones nonnullae analyticae* (Some analytic investigations on cubic residues), Crelle 32 (1846), Kummer studies cubic Gauss sums and connects these sums with L-series of cubic characters. He accomplishes this by using Fourier series and a very clever trick - I'm still trying to decipher his ideas, and I don't think this has been taken up by anyone at all. Kummer does not look at all at the simpler case of quadratic Gauss sums, where I think his methods yields a clever evaluation of $L(1,\chi)$ for quadratic characters,  let alone at the (rather trivial) case of the zeta function, but it is rather obvious that Kummer regarded these special cases 
(Leibniz series or Euler's $\zeta(2)$) as less interesting or at least as not novel - at the time he was trying to impress Jacobi and Dirichlet. Kummer does not give any sources, but at the end he remarks that some of his formulas for cubic residues may be proved directly without the analytic methods that he regards as being invented by himself.

Comment: I found the article at https://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN243919689_0032/PPN243919689_0032___log40.pdf and see at the start of section 4 (p. 350) that he writes down $\sum_{n \geq 0} \cos((2n+1)v)/(2n+1)^2 = \pi^2/8 - (\pi/4)v$ for $0 \leq v \leq \pi$. Setting $v = 0$ gives $\sum_{n \geq 0} 1/(2n+1)^2 = \pi^2/8$, from which $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ easily follows, although I don't see how Kummer evaluates that Fourier series to be a quadratic polynomial on $[0,\pi]$, and especially (key point) how he finds the constant term is $\pi^2/8$.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using Fourier series the fact that computing the Fourier expansion of e.g. linear functions such as $f(x) = x$ is a routine calculation?

Comment: Whoops, I should not have said "quadratic" polynomial. And now I see what you mean. If we start with the simple even triangular wave $f(x)=1−(2/\pi)|x|$ for $−\pi\leq x\leq\pi$, which has value $1$ in the middle, $−1$ at the endpoints, and repeats periodically outside $[-\pi,\pi]$, then $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere and its Fourier series is easily found to be $\sum_{n\geq 0} (8/(\pi^2(2n+1)^2))\cos((2n+1)x)$. Setting $x=0$, we get $\sum_{n \geq 0} 1/(2n+1)^2 = \pi^2/8$. The series Kummer wrote down is $(\pi^2/8)f(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$, but it's easier to imagine someone had worked out (contd.)

Comment: the Fourier series of the even triangular wave with max/min values $\pm 1$ and then found the sum of reciprocal odd squares and the expression $\pi^2/8$ coming out, although I don't know if that is what actually happened. It's hard to believe anyone would have started from the linear function on $[0,\pi]$ that appears in Kummer's paper and worked out the Fourier series of that.

Comment: For that matter, a more basic continuous even piecewise linear function is $|x|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, repeated periodically. Its Fourier series is $\pi/2 - \sum_{n \geq 0} (4/(\pi(2n+1)^2))\cos((2n+1)x)$. Setting $x = 0$ we get $\pi/2 = \sum_{n \geq 0} 4/(\pi(2n+1)^2)$, so $\sum_{n \geq 0} 1/(2n+1)^2 = \pi^2/8$. It would be good to find out who first developed some continuous even piecewise linear functions into Fourier series.

Comment: There must be examples in Fourier's Theorie de la chaleur - I'll have a look at it next week. The relevant parts seem to be available at http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/~mazliak/Fourier_1822.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found it there! On p. 241 Fourier gives the Fourier expansion in my previous comment (although there was no notation for $|x|$ at that time) but he does not evaluate it at $x=0$. Earlier, on p. 219 he gives the series $\sum_{n\geq1} 1/n^2$ the name $P$ and evaluates it as $\pi^2/6$ by Euler's method of factoring $\sin x$. The early part of this file has no integrals: Fourier coefficients are worked out by expanding functions into power series and comparing Taylor coefficients to get systems of linear equations. Later, starting on p. 232, he is using integrals.

Comment: Since Fourier himself produced the Fourier series for a periodized $|x|$, working out coefficients with integrals, we can say that he essentially "knew" how to evaluate $\sum_{n\geq 1} 1/n^2$ by Fourier series. The "only thing" to figure out now is if Euler or Bernoulli in their pre-Fourier work on Fourier series had ever done something along these lines for suitable examples.

Comment: The original question I asked, on behalf of someone else, was who first actually noticed Fourier analysis provides an evaluation of $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2$. In the link above to Fourier's work we can see that he sometimes does evaluate at specific $x$ to recover known results like the alternating odd harmonic series being $\pi/4$, but he does not (there) recognize the sum of $1/n^2$ as something that his work can explain.

Comment: Fourier would not have needed to invoke Euler - he could have evaluated his integration constant by plugging in $x = 0$ and $x = \pi/2$, if I remember it correctly.